# Remove key - value pairs from associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a query that returns an associative array. In that array are fields I must remove before output. I've tried array_diff and unset, but not having any luck.

The beginning array:

```
Array
(
  [id] => 13461
  [ln] => 605717
  [ptyp] => COND
  [lag] => 86484
  [st] => S
  [lp] => 475000
  [sp] => 475000
  [olp] => 475000
  [hsn] => 2033
)
```

I need to remove 3 items, whose value is different for every instance (key is the same). Here is what I've tried, but the output is not what I'm looking for.

```
    $result = array( ['id'] => '13461', ['ln'] => '605717', ['ptyp'] => 'COND', ['lag'] => '86484', ['st'] => 'S', ['lp'] => '475000', ['sp'] => '475000', ['olp'] => '475000', ['hsn'] => '2033');
    while ($row = $result) {

        // remove empty values
        $filtered = array_filter($row);

        // array of disallowed keys
        $disallowed = array($row['lp'],$row['lph'],$row['olp']);
        foreach ($filtered as $filter) {
            # code...
            unset($disallowed);
        }
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r ($filter);
            echo "</pre>";

    }
```

Edit: The items in my $disallowed array are not necessarily present in every row, but if they are they must be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I am understanding this correct. I would just remove the elements where the key matches your requirements.

```
$result = array( ['id'] => '13461', ['ln'] => '605717', ['ptyp'] => 'COND', ['lag'] => '86484', ['st'] => 'S', ['lp'] => '475000', ['sp'] => '475000', ['olp'] => '475000', ['hsn'] => '2033');
    while ($row = $result) {    
        // remove empty values
        $filtered = array_filter($row);    
        // define an array of disallowed keys
        $disallowed = array('lp','lph','olp');
        foreach ($disallowed as $disallowed_key) {
            // code...
            unset($row["$disallowed_key"]); // remove the element which key is not allowed
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r ($row); // output the final result with all disallowed elements removed
        echo "</pre>";

    }
```